# Enity framework with navigation property returning null value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

i have two model classes like categorymodel and images. my objective is to upload images under category the uploading parts are working just fine but the problem occurs when fetching the data. i would like to display the category data associated with the image.

1. [the model class image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbdXa.png)
2. [fetching and jsonifying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzfF8.png)

Comment: can you post your code in the question instead of providing a link?

Comment: What exactly is returning null? I noticed you have the `[Authorize]` attribute on your endpoint, are you authorized when trying to retrieve the images? Also, can you post all the code that is involved in this workflow? Upload & viewing? There's no way anyone can debug this as-is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is you are not loading your entites.  You either

1. Lazy load - make your navigation properties virtual.  This will automatically load your entities when needed.
2. Eager load - load the entity when you want. To do this you would want to do the following.

   ```
   var images = context.CategoryModel.Include(x=>x.Images).ToList();
   ```

Read here for more information on loading entities [loading entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)

Comment: `This will automatically load all your entities at once.` I don't think so, it's **lazy** so the entities are only loaded when needed.

Comment: @kienct89 you are correct.  That is what I really meant to say.  I edited the post.  Thanks.

Comment: I have done the early loading one and it worked but if I make the property virtual so will it work.